# How can I handle cases where a group of rows have the same identifier in mysql?

Tags: mysql

For example, in a log file, I have to collect events in a particular time and I have to store them in the database. How can I do that? The log file looks this:

Example:

Log file 1:

12/12/12 1:20:00.000    Start

12/12/12 1:20:00.000    Initialize

12/12/12 1:21:00.989    Stop

Log file 2:

12/12/12 1:20:00.000     Transmit

12/12/12 1:20:00.000     Hello

12/12/12 1:20:00.099     Receive

12/12/12 1:21:00.989     Bye

If I want the events during 12/12/12 1:20:00.000, I have more than one entry.How can I insert them into the database???

Comment: What does the log file look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a separate key, unrelated to the timestamp, when inserting the rows into a table. MySQL has a handy auto increment feature for this purpose.